# Enable requests to .git/HEAD in IIS

Tags: git, security, iis

With the very clear understanding that you should never, ever (ever) do this in your production environment, how do you enable IIS to serve requests to ".git/HEAD"? I wasn't sure if it was being blocked by request filtering or because of a missing MIME type but I can't get it to be served either by adding an allowable file extension in request filtering or by adding a MIME map.

Any ideas?

For context, this is part of project that demonstrates remotely exploitable risks, one of which is VCS repos accessible over HTTP. Unfortunately IIS does too good a job of looking after this by default!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a MIME Type mapping for '.' to 'application/octet-stream'. This will let IIS serve extension-less static files.

This works for me on IIS 10.0 (Windows 10).